# How do I setup SSH?

Tags: ssh

I originally installed `VSFTPD`, but my friend said it was unsecured and told me to install SSH. I just want to transfer files, and I am not sure what am I supposed to install, could someone please tell me what am I supposed to install?

I am using Debian

Comment: VS in VSFTP = Very secure heh. Funny. It's all about how you set it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VSFTPD is very secure if setup correctly. Use this [article](http://wiki.vpslink.com/Configuring_vsftpd_for_secure_connections_(TLS/SSL/SFTP))

Comment: Do you know of a guide for Debian?

Comment: Sure; there is tons of stuff on net. I would use the wiki. http://wiki.debian.org/Manual-Howto. The install for VSFTP is the first thing listed.

Comment: There is also this at linuxhomenetworking: http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:_Ch15_:_Linux_FTP_Server_Setup

Answer (score 4):

You probably already have the proper software installed. Most Linux distros come with an SSH server. What your friend is referring to is SFTP, which is basically just FTP over the SSH protocol. If you want to log in to the SFTP server, just give the SFTP client your SSH login info. Your SSH username is the username you are logged into Debian as. Your SSH password is your login password.